# Creating a Vewport3D camera in XAML is not working

Tags: c#, xaml, 3d, camera, viewport3d

I was trying to create a new Perspective Camera using C# and apply that to my XAML code, but for some reason, when I do it directly in XAML it works fine, but when I do it in C#, it does not work.

Here is the code I got from Microsoft's demonstration: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-create-a-3-d-scene?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

```
<Viewport3D
                        Name="SceneViewViewport" 
                        Width="954" 
                        Height="659">


                        <!-- Defines the camera used to view the 3D object. -->
                        <Viewport3D.Camera>
                            <PerspectiveCamera Position="0,0,2" LookDirection="0,0,-1" FieldOfView="60" />
                        </Viewport3D.Camera>

                        <!-- The ModelVisual3D children contain the 3D models -->
                        <Viewport3D.Children>

                            <!-- This ModelVisual3D defines the light cast in the scene. Without light, the 3D 
                 object cannot be seen. Also, the direction of the lights affect shadowing. If desired,
                 you can create multiple lights with different colors that shine from different directions. -->
                            <ModelVisual3D>
                                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                                    <DirectionalLight Color="#FFFFFF" Direction="-0.612372,-0.5,-0.612372" />
                                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
                            </ModelVisual3D>
                            <ModelVisual3D>
                                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                                    <GeometryModel3D>

                                        <!-- The geometry specifies the shape of the 3D plane. In this sample, a flat sheet is created. -->
                                        <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                            <MeshGeometry3D
                     TriangleIndices="0,1,2 3,4,5 "
                     Normals="0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 "
                     TextureCoordinates="0,0 1,0 1,1 1,1 0,1 0,0 "
                     Positions="-0.5,-0.5,0.5 0.5,-0.5,0.5 0.5,0.5,0.5 0.5,0.5,0.5 -0.5,0.5,0.5 -0.5,-0.5,0.5 " />
                                        </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>

                                        <!-- The material specifies the material applied to the 3D object. In this sample a linear gradient 
                       covers the surface of the 3D object.-->
                                        <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                            <MaterialGroup>
                                                <DiffuseMaterial>
                                                    <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
                                                            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                                <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0" />
                                                                <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.25" />
                                                                <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.75" />
                                                                <GradientStop Color="LimeGreen" Offset="1" />
                                                            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                                </DiffuseMaterial>
                                            </MaterialGroup>
                                        </GeometryModel3D.Material>

                                        <!-- Apply a transform to the object. In this sample, a rotation transform is applied, rendering the 
                       3D object rotated. -->
                                        <GeometryModel3D.Transform>
                                            <RotateTransform3D>
                                                <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                                    <AxisAngleRotation3D Axis="0,3,0" Angle="40" />
                                                </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                            </RotateTransform3D>
                                        </GeometryModel3D.Transform>
                                    </GeometryModel3D>
                                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
                            </ModelVisual3D>
                        </Viewport3D.Children>


                    </Viewport3D>
```

Works fine.

Now I put the same code (C#) version, also from Microsoft's demo, and it does not work.

```
viewport = (Viewport3D)FindName("SceneViewViewport");

            SceneViewWidth = (float)viewport.Width;
            SceneViewHeight = (float)viewport.Height;

            Setup();
```

```
void Setup()
        {
            // Declare scene objects.
            Viewport3D myViewport3D = viewport;
            Model3DGroup myModel3DGroup = new Model3DGroup();
            GeometryModel3D myGeometryModel = new GeometryModel3D();
            ModelVisual3D myModelVisual3D = new ModelVisual3D();
            // Defines the camera used to view the 3D object. In order to view the 3D object,
            // the camera must be positioned and pointed such that the object is within view
            // of the camera.
            PerspectiveCamera myPCamera = new PerspectiveCamera();

            // Specify where in the 3D scene the camera is.
            myPCamera.Position = new Point3D(0, 0, 2);

            // Specify the direction that the camera is pointing.
            myPCamera.LookDirection = new Vector3D(0, 0, -1);

            // Define camera's horizontal field of view in degrees.
            myPCamera.FieldOfView = 70;

            // Asign the camera to the viewport
            viewport.Camera = myPCamera;
            
            // Define the lights cast in the scene. Without light, the 3D object cannot
            // be seen. Note: to illuminate an object from additional directions, create
            // additional lights.
            DirectionalLight myDirectionalLight = new DirectionalLight();
            myDirectionalLight.Color = Colors.White;
            myDirectionalLight.Direction = new Vector3D(-0.61, -0.5, -0.61);

            myModel3DGroup.Children.Add(myDirectionalLight);

            // The geometry specifes the shape of the 3D plane. In this sample, a flat sheet
            // is created.
            MeshGeometry3D myMeshGeometry3D = new MeshGeometry3D();

            // Create a collection of normal vectors for the MeshGeometry3D.
            Vector3DCollection myNormalCollection = new Vector3DCollection();
            myNormalCollection.Add(new Vector3D(0, 0, 1));
            myNormalCollection.Add(new Vector3D(0, 0, 1));
            myNormalCollection.Add(new Vector3D(0, 0, 1));
            myNormalCollection.Add(new Vector3D(0, 0, 1));
            myNormalCollection.Add(new Vector3D(0, 0, 1));
            myNormalCollection.Add(new Vector3D(0, 0, 1));
            myMeshGeometry3D.Normals = myNormalCollection;

            // Create a collection of vertex positions for the MeshGeometry3D.
            Point3DCollection myPositionCollection = new Point3DCollection();
            myPositionCollection.Add(new Point3D(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5));
            myPositionCollection.Add(new Point3D(0.5, -0.5, 0.5));
            myPositionCollection.Add(new Point3D(0.5, 0.5, 0.5));
            myPositionCollection.Add(new Point3D(0.5, 0.5, 0.5));
            myPositionCollection.Add(new Point3D(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5));
            myPositionCollection.Add(new Point3D(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5));
            myMeshGeometry3D.Positions = myPositionCollection;

            // Create a collection of texture coordinates for the MeshGeometry3D.
            PointCollection myTextureCoordinatesCollection = new PointCollection();
            myTextureCoordinatesCollection.Add(new Point(0, 0));
            myTextureCoordinatesCollection.Add(new Point(1, 0));
            myTextureCoordinatesCollection.Add(new Point(1, 1));
            myTextureCoordinatesCollection.Add(new Point(1, 1));
            myTextureCoordinatesCollection.Add(new Point(0, 1));
            myTextureCoordinatesCollection.Add(new Point(0, 0));
            myMeshGeometry3D.TextureCoordinates = myTextureCoordinatesCollection;

            // Create a collection of triangle indices for the MeshGeometry3D.
            Int32Collection myTriangleIndicesCollection = new Int32Collection();
            myTriangleIndicesCollection.Add(0);
            myTriangleIndicesCollection.Add(1);
            myTriangleIndicesCollection.Add(2);
            myTriangleIndicesCollection.Add(3);
            myTriangleIndicesCollection.Add(4);
            myTriangleIndicesCollection.Add(5);
            myMeshGeometry3D.TriangleIndices = myTriangleIndicesCollection;

            // Apply the mesh to the geometry model.
            myGeometryModel.Geometry = myMeshGeometry3D;

            // The material specifies the material applied to the 3D object. In this sample a
            // linear gradient covers the surface of the 3D object.

            // Create a horizontal linear gradient with four stops.
            LinearGradientBrush myHorizontalGradient = new LinearGradientBrush();
            myHorizontalGradient.StartPoint = new Point(0, 0.5);
            myHorizontalGradient.EndPoint = new Point(1, 0.5);
            myHorizontalGradient.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Yellow, 0.0));
            myHorizontalGradient.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Red, 0.25));
            myHorizontalGradient.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Blue, 0.75));
            myHorizontalGradient.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.LimeGreen, 1.0));

            // Define material and apply to the mesh geometries.
            DiffuseMaterial myMaterial = new DiffuseMaterial(myHorizontalGradient);
            myGeometryModel.Material = myMaterial;

            // Apply a transform to the object. In this sample, a rotation transform is applied,
            // rendering the 3D object rotated.
            RotateTransform3D myRotateTransform3D = new RotateTransform3D();
            AxisAngleRotation3D myAxisAngleRotation3d = new AxisAngleRotation3D();
            myAxisAngleRotation3d.Axis = new Vector3D(0, 3, 0);
            myAxisAngleRotation3d.Angle = 40;
            myRotateTransform3D.Rotation = myAxisAngleRotation3d;
            myGeometryModel.Transform = myRotateTransform3D;

            // Add the geometry model to the model group.
            myModel3DGroup.Children.Add(myGeometryModel);

            // Add the group of models to the ModelVisual3d.
            myModelVisual3D.Content = myModel3DGroup;

            //
            myViewport3D.Children.Add(myModelVisual3D);

            // Apply the viewport to the page so it will be rendered.
            
            this.Content = myViewport3D;
        }
```

I tried using Microsoft's example, found here: "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-create-a-3-d-scene?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8", but nothing changed. The XAML version works as expected, but the C# version only displays an empty screen.